# Create an optional field in Zend_Form (only validate if provided, OK if missing though)

Tags: php, zend-framework

As you can see, I want to make the username optional. So, I don't want to setRequired(true) because that will validate as false if the field is missing (this is for an update PUT so only update what is PUT to the API, if username is missing, don't update. If username is present though, it should be validated)

```
<?php

class UA_Form_NewAccount extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        .
        .
        .

        // username
        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        // $username->setRequired(true);
        $username->setLabel('Username');
        $username->addValidator('NotEmpty');
        $this->addElement($username);

        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

..I've also tried the configration as an array approach but always the same results:

```
    // required - first name
    $this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
        'label' => 'Username',
        // 'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            'NotEmpty',
        )
    ));
```

What I find though is without setRequired(true), validator doesn't run. So, if I PUT "username=somethinginvalid" it won't validate unless I setRequired(true). But, this makes the field required, which I don't want. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont get it, where do you have a problem... because NotEmpty and setRequired is same thing for text input. Its should validate with other classes without required field

Comment: What kind of validation do you need? If it is just optional then there is no need to set setRequired() to true.

Comment: NotEmpty and setRequired are not the same to my understanding. setRequired insists that the parameter be present, but also validates with NotEmpty by default. NotEmpty by itself will only validate if the parameter is given, if the parameter is missing then it will not consider this invalid. I don't want to use setRequired, as the parameter is optional. I do want to use NonEmpty if the parameter is given. But, NonEmpty validatator doesn't seem to run when I remove setRequired, even in instances where the parameter is present.